# XSLT condition based on output tree

Tags: xslt, tree

I'm used to having conditions in my XSLT that are based on the tree of nodes in the input. But I want to do it based on the output. Is there any way?

Here's an example.

Input:

```
<top>
    <a>
        <z>
            <item>
                <id>4</id>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>5</id>
            </item>
        </z>
    </a>
</top>
```

Desired output:

```
<thing>
    <upper>
        <a>
            <z>
                <item>
                    <id>upper-4</id>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <id>upper-5</id>
                </item>
            </z>
        </a>
    </upper>
    <lower>
        <a>
            <z>
                <item>
                    <id>lower-4</id>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <id>lower-5</id>
                </item>
            </z>
        </a>
    </lower>
</thing>
```

Notice that the tree is essentially duplicated from a downwards, the only changes are that the values of the `id` node have been modified depending if we're in the `upper` or `lower` trees.

My current XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:template match="top">
        <thing>
            <upper>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </upper>
            <lower>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </lower>
        </thing>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id">
        <!-- I want to prepend this with "upper" or "lower" depending which block we're in -->
        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is a simplified example, there are many nodes in the tree between `a` and `z`, and the `item` nodes can appear are various depths under `a`.

Initially I started with a condition that looked like `ancestor::upper`, but obviously that doesn't work because `upper` is in the output, not the input.

I've also considered trying to pass a parameter through to say if we're in `upper` or `lower`, but that means updating every single template (including the identity template) to have a param and also to pass it through to any templates it calls. I really want to avoid this if possible.

So, if there's a way to pass variables through to called templates without having to declare the varaible, that would work. Or if I can write a condition that looks at the templates that called us or the output in the tree above us, that would work. Or are there any other ways to do this?

Note that I'm using the Saxon processor, so I can use features specific to that (e.g. I could call out to some java if that would help).

Thanks.

Comment: Your code says `version="2.0"` yet Xalan is an XSLT 1.0 processor. If you switch to Saxon 9 and really use XSLT 2.0 then you could use tunnel parameters to avoid having to pass the parameter on with every apply-templates. Other than that I think the parameter is the right approach.

Comment: @MartinHonnen sorry, I meant Saxon... (I'm using version 9.1.0.8 currently) I will look into tunnel parameters though, I've not come across them before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using a tunnel parameter with XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="top">
        <thing>
            <upper>
                <xsl:apply-templates>
                  <xsl:with-param name="tree-id" tunnel="yes" select="'upper-'"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </upper>
            <lower>
                <xsl:apply-templates>
                  <xsl:with-param name="tree-id" tunnel="yes" select="'lower-'"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </lower>
        </thing>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id">
        <xsl:param name="tree-id" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:copy>
          <!-- I want to prepend this with "upper" or "lower" depending which block we're in -->
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($tree-id, .)" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect - I'd not come across tunnel params before, thanks for that.